# What is wrong with this MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

It's 12:30am and I have been coding for 9 hours straight. I really need to get this project done, but MySQL is messing with my deadline. Could you examine this snippet for me and see if you can find out what is wrong?

**PHP/MySQL Query**

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE ip='".$ip."'");
```

Keeps returning the following error...

> MYSQL Error [Oct 6th, 2010 11:31pm CDT]
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM bans WHERE ip='206.53.90.231'' at line 1 (1064)

I do not see anything wrong with the query. I've even tried different methods of including the variable **$ip** but with no avail.

**EDIT:**
Just to add in here, the **ip** column in my database is a varchar(255).

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the whole affected code. Keep in mind that this is all in a class. If I'm missing something, let me know.

*Line from another Function*

```
if($this->isBanned($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])===true) { return json_encode(array('error'=>'You are banned from this ShoutBox.')); }
```

*Affected Function*

```
function isBanned($ip) {
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE ip='".$ip."'"); $num = $this->db->affected_rows;
    if($num>0) { $row = $this->db->fetch_array($q); if(($row['expires'] < time()) && ($row['expires'] !== 0)) { $this->unbanUser($ip,'internal'); return false; } return true; } return false;
}
```

*unbanUser function*

```
function unbanUser($ip,$t='box') {
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE ip='".$ip."'"); $num = $this->db->affected_rows; if($num>0) { $q = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM bans WHERE ip='".$ip."'"); 
    return (($t=='box') ? json_encode(array('status'=>'removed')) : true); } else { return (($t=='box') ? json_encode(array('error'=>'Unable to locate the user.')) : true); }
}
```

Comment: Try printing `$ip` just before the query

Comment: Strange, even if you did escape it with `mysql_real_escape_string()` in your database class that shouldn't affect the IP string your error is talking about...

Comment: The query looks correct, assuming there aren't any odd non-printing chars in there.  The error it's seeing is at the `*` . I assume the string is all ASCII, not UTF-8?

Comment: If you had copied and pasted the code, check to see if the space after SELECT is really a space. Better type the entire query manually and check.

Comment: Does the query work from the mysql command line?

Comment: @codaddict- Just did and returns the normal ip address without any special characters.

Comment: Have you tried to use backticks to escape identifiers (`bans` and `ip`)? Maybe you can try to remove all non digits and dots characters from the IP string as well... Just my 2 cents. But that's indeed weird.

Comment: @belwood - Yep, it does.  @Nirmal - It's not copied and pasted :/  @cHao - Yea, everything was typed by myself. The database is UTF-8 but that should not affect the query.  @BoltClock's a Unicorn - I even tried escaping it, but with no avail.

Comment: adding an edit to the main post.

Comment: It's silly to ask, but did you accidentally define any value for the variable `SELECT` in PHP? I could think of nothing else.

Comment: @Nirmal - Nope :/ I try to stray away from define due to the conflicts.  The main post has been updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>I think it may be</strike> It is your `DELETE` statement which is causing the error.

Remove the `*` after the `DELETE` and it should be fine.

Comment: It is definitively the `DELETE` that is causing the issue here.

Comment: Oh my god. I was writing too many queries today and completely was not thinking straight when it came to <pre>DELETE</pre>. Yea, that fixed my issues. Thank you very much for helping me out on this one.

Comment: That's the knot in the story!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM bans WHERE ip="' . $ip . '"');
```

Comment: What difference would that make to MySQL?

Comment: Yea, exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Actually, the SQL standard says that string literals MUST be single-quoted, but MySQL allows double quotes (double quotes in the SQL standard are analogous to MySQL's back quotes). This might save you few hours of head scratching if you ever use a different DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the ' character or the ´ character (the last one is an accent)

Comment: I'm using ' not ´ but it has never mattered.